# Regex for length of substring

Tags: php, regex, string

I receive a string conformed by numbers and points. I need those numbers to have a minimum length of 3, so, I have to add one or more zeros in from of the numbers with a lower length.

Example:

If I have:

```
233.14.205.1.194056.270132
```

I need it to be:

```
233.014.205.001.194056.270132
    ↑       ↑↑
```

(Note the `014` where there was a `14` and the `001` where there was a `1`)

I know I can explode the string, add the zeros I need and implode it again, but I want not to create a function for something that can solved with a native function (`preg_replace`) and I am not very good with regex (yet).

Comment: Regular Expressions aren't really going to be suited for string manipulation like this. You are likely going to be better off just using the `explode()` > `str_pad()` > `implode()` approach. It'll likely be much more readable and understandable than a regex that could accomplish the same.

Answer (score 1):

Using `explode -> zero padding -> implode` will indeed be straight forward.

Since you're specifically asking for `preg_replace` way of doing it here it is:

```
$s = '233.14.205.1.194056.270132'

$repl = preg_replace(array('/\b\d\b/', '/\b\d\d\b/'), array('00$0', '0$0'), $s);
//=> 233.014.205.001.194056.270132
```

Here we're passing a 2 element array of regex to `preg_replace` and inserting singe or double zeroes before the matched double/single digit.

Comment: Assumes knowledge of the string which would negate the necessity of this question - also not handling the possible padding needed for the first set of numbers. If you know/can assume these things, you could just add put zeros in to the right spot in the string. Doesn't feel like a real answer to me. This is where I was headed but had some similar problems: `echo preg_replace('/\.(\d{0,2})\.+/', '.'.substr('000$1', -3).'.', '233.14.205.1.194056.270132');` (first set not handled, not properly padding between 1 or 2 character strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this replacement:

```
$str = preg_replace('~\.(?!\d{3})|(?=\b\d\b)~', '${0}0', $str);
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/fK7lY2/1)

The pattern uses two branches:

- the first matches a dot not followed by 3 digits (in this case the replacement is the dot and an additional zero)
- the second matches only the position before a single digit (in this case the replacement is only a zero since the whole match is empty).

When there are already two digits, only the first branch succeeds, but when there's only one digit the first branch succeeds and the second branch succeeds too at the next position in the string *(immediately after the dot)*.

Note that you can use this pattern only for three digits, you can't extend it for more digits. A way that works for the number of digits you want can be:

```
$str = array_reduce(explode('.', $str), function ($c,$i) {
    return sprintf("%s%s%03d", $c, empty($c)?'':'.', $i);
});
```

or:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('~\b\d{1,2}\b~', function ($m) {
    return sprintf("%03d", $m[0]);
}, $str);
```

Comment: would be able, upvote it few times :)  i did not thinking that it may be done in two steps

Answer (score 0):

You likely don't need a regular expression for this as you could simply split your string into an array via the [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function and then pad each of your sections via [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`str_pad()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) respectively then finally use [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to fit everything back together :

```
$input = '233.14.205.1.194056.270132';
$output = implode(".",array_map(function($s) { return str_pad($s,3,"0", STR_PAD_LEFT); },explode(".",$input)));
```